# Unexpected token syntax error I can not see

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, react-server

Thanks for taking a look. This is the syntax error I am getting:

```
[0] /Users/alexkarasik/Documents/server/services/passport.js:26
[0] async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
[0]       ^
[0] SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
```

and this is the file that error is referencing. I've been looking thing up and down now for over 2 hours and see no reason to be getting this error:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const keys = require('../config/keys');

const User = mongoose.model('users');

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id)
    .then(user => {
      done(null, user);
    })
});

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: keys.googleClientID,
    clientSecret: keys.googleClientSecret,
    callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback',
    proxy: true
  },
async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id });

    if (existingUser){
            //we already have a record with the give profileId
            return done(null, existingUser);
    }
            // we don't have a user record with this ID, make a new record
      const user = await new User({ googleId: profile.id }).save();
      done(null, user);
    }
  )
);
```

I really appreciate any input.

Comment: Does your server fully support ESnext? ( especially async await..)

Comment: @Jonasw is probably right. Do you have a webpack config file or a babelrc setup?

Comment: @sourRasperri webpack? What has this todo with serverside code? And why should one babel if youcan simply update bodejs?

Comment: You could drop back to Promise handling using something like this:
`(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
  User.findOne({
            googleId : profile.id
        }).exec().then(
            (existingUser)=>{
                /* [...] */
            }
        ); }`

Comment: In what environment are you trying to run this code, what exactly does throw this error?

Answer (score 0):

Node was just not updated properly for the newer ES6 syntax. Updating it solved this issue. Thank you for your help.